# "The book brought me 300 francs, which I had to PUT UP" -- what's the meaning of "put up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, translation

By Gustave Flaubert:

> We are workers of luxury. Thus nobody is rich enough to pay us. When you want to earn money with your pen, you have to do journalism, serials or the theatre. *Bovary* brought me 300 francs, which I had to **PUT UP**, and I will never make a cent from it. Right now I manage to pay for my paper, but not the errands, trips and books that I need for my work; and, in the end, I find that all right (or I pretend to find it all right), because I don’t see what relation there is between a five-franc coin and an idea. You have to love Art for Art’s sake; otherwise, the humblest job is worth more.

What is the meaning of "put up" here? The author capitalized the phrase. Is it "to store for future use"? But why such emphasis?

I looked up "[put up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_up)" in Wiktionary, but there's a huge list of meanings.

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's sense 9 on the wiktionary page.  To provide funds in advance, as in to invest some money before you can make that money back.

Comment: It's presumably translated, so it might not be exactly accurate. To my mind, *Bovary **brought** me 300 francs* means *that's how much he got paid for it*. But *which I had to **put up*** implies he had to *put that much money up front* (cf "vanity publishing"), so the only way I can understand it is if Flaubert is saying he didn't *actually* earn any money at all from the book, because all he got back was his own 300 francs that he's had to pay to get it published in the first place. So, unlikely as it might seem, the book neither paid nor cost Flaubert anything - it exactly ***broke even***.

Comment: (I see no good reason for the translator capitalising that phrasal verb, which presumably doesn't reflect anything unusual about the original French.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a highly suspect translation

Comment: This is **translated from French**. I suggest you find the original in French.

Comment: The French is this: La Bovary m’a rapporté... 300 francs, que J’AI PAYÉS, et je n’en toucherai jamais un centime. It is not "put up". It's merely: 300 francs that I PAID. [not explained any further by the author.]

Comment: @Lambie - thank you! I should have looked for the original.

Comment: I would have translated ***m'a rapporté*** as ***brought me in*** (i.e. - ***earned** me*), but perhaps the meaning of that has changed over time. But in English he probably wouldn't have said the book ***earned*** money if that exact same amount of money had to be paid to publish it anyway. He'd just say it ***covered its costs** [but didn't actually earn him any **profit / return on "investment"**]*.

Comment: The issue is not anything other than payés. The entire thing is: Bovary [the novel] only brought in 300 francs for me, which I paid. There is no idea of him paying out any money. The French is just not **clear**.

Comment: @Lambie re your last comment: Did you mean "... no idea of him (**putting up**) any money" ?Otherwise I don't see any difference between 'paying' and 'paying out'.

Comment: @PapaPoule Yes, there is no idea about putting up money in the French. It clearly says he paid 300 francs, punto. putting up or paying out could be seen as related, neither works here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is well known that publishing *Madame Bovary* did not bring Flaubert any money, and in fact cost him 300 francs that he had to pay. (*Mme Bovary m'ayant, de bénéfice net, couté 300 francs*). That is the reason for the emphasis.

This agrees with this meaning of 'put up' -

> Put up
>
> Phrasal verb
>
> 4. TRANSITIVE to provide a large amount of money for something
>
> The family has put up £15,000 towards the cost of the child’s medical
> treatment.
>
> Synonyms and related words: to spend or to pay money, disburse, spend, pay

[Put up (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-up)

Comment: Losing money is not the same thing as putting up an amount of money.

Comment: @Lambie - my answer makes it clear that he had to pay 300 francs, out of his own money to clear the debt/make things square (with the publisher?) (m'a couté 300 francs = 'cost me 300 francs'). I think instead of 'put up', 'fork out', or 'provide out of my own funds'  might be better alternatives.

Comment: The French does not say that. That's the problem. The problem is not with the idea in English.

Comment: Usually *put up* would mean something along the lines of supply a (usually refundable) deposit though, right?  When I hear *put up*, I presume that you hope for a refund at some future date

Comment: @Cullub The "refund" was for *Mme Bovary* to be published. [put up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/put-up-something): to provide money so that an aim can be achieved: Dad put $1000 up to help me buy a car.*

Comment: @Cullub - no. To put up can simply mean to make a payment so that something can happen. This is shown in the answer above.

Comment: @Lambie The French definitely says that by emphasizing *j'AI PAYÉS*. Flaubert sentence is kind of a "profit and loss" statement. The money he made (*300 francs*) balances his costs (*j'AI PAYÉS*) so no profit was made from this book.

Comment: @jlliagre - so explain this "Mme Bovary m'ayant, de bénéfice net, _couté 300 francs_"

Comment: You are right, the handwritten letter from which you picked that sentence makes it clear. Flaubert used *rapporté* ironically and the net loss was 300 francs.

Comment: @jlliagre - These comments give me an idea for a film script - after _Les quatre cents coups_, what about _Les trois cents francs_? I have in mind Romain Duris or Fabrice Luchini for the role. You could argue that both are a bit old (Flaubert was 35) , but hey! we made the film some years ago, didn't we? Luchini is my absolute favourite film actor. À propos de rien, I once heard a French TV newsreader explain Charles Dickens as 'le Victor Hugo anglais'. I am not sure if either need feel aggrieved. A French temp told me she once saw Luchini in a Monoprix buying some yogurt. I was so jealous.

Comment: I like Lucchini too. He is never boring, has a unique way of expressing himself, a brilliant sense of humour and repartee. By the way, Lucchini's daughter is named Emma after Flaubert's Emma Bovary.

Comment: @jlliagre - Luchini can do more acting with his eyes than many actors manage with the whole of their bodies. I usually start laughing about 30 seconds into a film where he appears. Yes, Emma, his daughter. He was, unfortunately, in a really, truly dire thing called Gemma Bovery ("neuters Flaubert’s protag" - _Variety_) with the wooden Gemma Arterton.